# jwplayer doesn't play well in Angular Elements

Tags: jwplayer, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have this Angular component with embedded jwplayer that works fine.
When I try to create a custom element out of it with Angular Elements or try to use "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native", the jwplayer will fail to initialize.  jwplayer is loaded, I can see it in window object.

```
core.js:1604 ERROR TypeError: jwplayer(id).setup is not a function
    at t.setupPlayer (jw-player.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:70)
    at HTMLScriptElement.S (zone.js:1188)
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4034)
    at t.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at e.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
    at k (zone.js:1540)
    at HTMLScriptElement._ (zone.js:1566)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the loaded library (https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/6gLLM4B1.js). It looks up the video element using `document.getElementById(...)` and it also uses `document.body` sometimes. However, the video element is the `JwPlayerComponent` and if you activate Shadow DOM on the root component this element is hidden within the Shadow DOM.

On the other side, you could provide it as an Angular Element/ Custom Element using `ViewEncapsulation.Native`. To make this work, I had to introduce some modifications to the project:

- Remove the selector b/c it conflicts with the name of the custom element (`// selector: 'wu-player-element'`)
- Also remove the bootstrap section of your module (`//bootstrap: [AppComponent]`)
- Modify your `tsconfig.app.json`: Add `"target": "es2015",` b/c Custom Elements do not work with the way, TypeScript downlevels classes to ES5

If you need ES5 nethertheless, you could use a polyfill (native-shim.js), see: https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/13/angular-elements-part-i-a-dynamic-dashboard-in-four-steps-with-web-components.aspx

Comment: actually that didn't quite work, the build failed silently with the script so it never produced a js file, it was the old one that I have commented out ViewEncapsulation.Native.  Following the instructions above it was throwing these errors at build time when set "target": "es2015"

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/angular-playground/projects/wu-player/src'

Comment: Totally lost sight of this. Is the issue resolved or can I still help somehow?